# How does caching works for many to one mapping in hibernate

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I have two entities station and company .
Station has many to one mapping with company. When Iam trying to fetch the list of stations based on company . It always hit the database. Below is my station entity class

```
@Table(name = "station")
@Setter
@Getter
@Builder

@Cacheable
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
public class Station  {
    public Station() {}
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "mySeqGen", sequenceName = "station_seq",allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "mySeqGen")

    @Column(name = "station_id ")
    private Long id;
    Double latitude;
    Double longitude;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY , cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "company_id" , unique =true)
    @Fetch(value = FetchMode.JOIN)
```

Below is my code to find station list based on company

```
@Override
    public List<StationDTO> findStations(final FindStationRequestDTO findStationRequestDTO) {
        var company =  companyRepository.findById(findStationRequestDTO.getRequestCompanyId());
        var stationList =  stationRepository.findByCompany(company);
        return stationList.stream().map( station -> stationMapper.convertToStationDto(station , new StationDTO())).collect(Collectors.toList());


    }
```

caching is working for companyRepository.findById(findStationRequestDTO.getRequestCompanyId());

Answer (score 0):

```
public interface  StationRepository extends JpaRepository<Station, Long> {
    @QueryHints({
            @QueryHint(name = HINT_CACHEABLE, value = "true")

    })
      List<Station> findByCompany(final Optional<Company> company);

}
```

adding QueryHints made it working